# Drupal 7 wysiwyg editor is not showing in rules 'send mail' action email body field

Tags: drupal, html-email, wysiwyg, rules

I have an issue with wysiwyg editor in drupal 7, it is not showing for rules 'send mail' action email body field.

Wysiwyg editor is showing in node body but not in any admin email body fields.

I have also installed html mail module.